# No puedo instalar ningún paquete desde Nuget.org

Tags: c#, nuget

Estaba intentando hacer una API sencilla en C# y conectarla a una base de datos de SQLServer en local, pero no puedo instalar el paquete [Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore/9.0.0-preview.1.24081.2) desde la pagina de NuGet, el comando para instalarlo se encuentra en la misma pagina y en la imagen debajo. Por la consola veo que intenta hacer el fetch pero recibe 404 por todos lados... algo así recibo por consola:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es mucho mas largo pero básicamente hace varios fetchings y fallan todos, y no me pasa solo con 1 paquete, sino con todos los que quiero instalar de esa pagina.

Estoy usando VSCode. En el momento del error estoy en el mismo directorio del proyecto, que es de tipo **"ASP.Net Core Web Api"** que se crea mediante unas plantillas de proyectos personalizadas. Los orígenes de NuGet registrados son los siguientes:

```
  1.  nuget.org [Habilitado]
      https://www.nuget.org/
  2.  Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages [Deshabilitado]
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\
```

La verdad no entiendo que esta pasando, los paquetes no se instalan de ninguna manera. Cualquier ayuda se agradece. Soy nuevo en C#.

Answer (score 1):

era cuestión de ir a los orígenes registrados de Nuget en *Visual Studio > Herramientas > Administrador de paquetes de Nuget > Configuracion* y cambiar este origen:

```
https://www.nuget.org/
```

Por este:

```
https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json
```

Al parecer ese archivo json es el que proporciona metadatos sobre los paquetes disponibles, incluyendo información sobre versiones, dependencias y otros detalles importantes.

Lo dejo por si a alguien le sirve.